# Adding controls into dynamic grid view in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I need to create grid view and add controls dynamically.

But I'm getting **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**.

I attached error as a Image because site shows some invalid characters in my error..

[image: see error here]

Comment: Please post the code text, not the screenshots. Thanks.

Comment: I tired to post code text but site doesn't allowed it Because of invalid characters.